# How to edit and delete the row in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

When I click table row, that row value will display the below text box, then  I click <kbd>+</kbd> button to copy the first row values and insert new row and place value correctly.

When I click edit button <kbd>#</kbd> that value again place to first row. How to find that row index. How to get the particular ID?

```
<script>
function insRow()
      {
          var x=document.getElementById('scrolltable');
          var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);


          var len = x.rows.length;

          var code=document.getElementById('code').value;
          var product=document.getElementById('product_name').value;
          var qty=document.getElementById('quantity').value;
          var rate=document.getElementById('amount').value;
          var amount=document.getElementById('total').value;

          var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          inp1.id += len;
          inp1.value = code;
          var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          inp2.id += len;
          inp2.value = product;
          var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          inp3.id += len;
          inp3.value = qty;
          var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          inp4.id += len;
          inp4.value = rate;
          var inp5 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          inp5.id += len;
          inp5.value = amount;


          var button = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          button.value = "#";
          button.onclick = function(it) {editRow(it)};

          //cell4.appendChild(inp4);

          x.appendChild( new_row );
          document.getElementById('code').value='';
          document.getElementById('product_name').value='';
          document.getElementById('quantity').value='';
          document.getElementById('amount').value='';
          document.getElementById('total').value='';
          document.getElementById('code').focus();
      }  
function deleteRow(row)
      {


          r=row.parentNode.parentNode;
        r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
      }

        function editRow(evt) {
            var x=document.getElementById('scrolltable');
            //var l1 = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode;
            //alert(l1);

            var errorList = "";
            var l=x.rows.length;
            //var l=x.rowsIndex;
            var y=l-1;
            alert(l);
            //alert("code"+y);
            var code=document.getElementById('code'+y).value;
          var product=document.getElementById('product_name'+y).value;
          var qty=document.getElementById('quantity'+y).value;
          var rate=document.getElementById('amount'+y).value;
          var amount=document.getElementById('total'+y).value;


                document.getElementById('code').value=code;
                      document.getElementById('product_name').value=product;
                document.getElementById('quantity').value=qty;
                document.getElementById('amount').value=rate;
                document.getElementById('total').value=amount;


            var i = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById('scrolltable').deleteRow(i);
            }
    </script>
```

My HTML code is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dTableR" id="scrolltable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="10%">Code</th>
<th width="40%">Product</th>
<th width="10%">Total Qty</th>
<th width="10%">Rate</th>
<th width="12%">Amount</th>
<th width="10%">Action</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code"  class="span10" id="code" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_name"   class="span12" id="product_name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="span10" onBlur="calculate(this.value)" id="quantity" maxlength="8"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount_name" class="span10" id="amount" /></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="total_name" class="span10" id="total" maxlength="8" /></td>
 <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" style="width:25px;" value="+" onClick="insRow()"/>
<input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" style="width:25px;" value="-" onClick="deleteRow(this)"/></td> 
</tr>                                    
</tbody>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NXWNJ/

Comment: this is working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NXWNJ/7/

Comment: do you want row index of '#' button row?

Comment: yes its working for me, i add 3 row values,when i click # button, that particular value return to first row

Comment: yes '#' button row move to top row, when i click.....now last row only move

Comment: not getting what is your requirement. Right now, on click of '#', row getting disappear and data moving to top row. what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: i want on click of '#',that particular row getting disappear and data moving to top row.

Comment: this is already working.

Comment: no, the last row  only move to top,,,if you add 3 rows, then click middle row,it doesn't move

Comment: Excuse me you got my question i think, kindly answer my question please@Bhushan Kawadkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery for edit function :

First change

```
button.onclick = function(it) {editRow(it)};
```

to

```
button.onclick = function() {editRow(this)};
```

and change below function

```
 function editRow(evt) 
   {

      var $tr = $(evt).parents('tr'); // get parent tr

      // put all values in top row
      $('#code').val($tr.find('input[id^=code]').val());
      $('#product_name').val($tr.find('input[id^=product_name]').val());
      $('#quantity').val($tr.find('input[id^=quantity]').val());
      $('#amount').val($tr.find('input[id^=amount]').val());
      $('#total').val($tr.find('input[id^=total]').val());

       // remove clicked tr
       $tr.remove();
   }
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXWNJ/16/)

**Note** : Please add jQuery js file to your html page.

Comment: in my page, two table is there.in left side normal html table and right side ajax table. when i click html table, that particular row values like(code,product and rate) will be placed in below text box..in my problem is, when i click ajax table, that particular row values will not place the textbox.. i want to place that ajax table values in textbox.(ajax table is auto refreshed)

Comment: see this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9sFGz/) my ajax table look like this table. when i click this table row automatically row row value place below text box

Comment: see this jsfiddle file (http://jsfiddle.net/anichandran/Xp54u/10/) i want this type. normal html table its work better,, but ajax table its not suited... in my page just call the ajax page link. the table content will be in ajax page(table value retieve from mysql).  @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: try to add event lister when loading ajax table.

Comment: any example for event listener...i am new for this concept

Comment: is this possible my concept.kindly suggest any idea @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: I have change second select box from left side to No Wrap - in <head> and it is working ... I think your ajax table should work with same script. You need to call run function after loadind ajax table and make sure that table id = myTable.

Comment: sorry i can't understand.. this is my page code    <div class="main-container-right" style="float:right;width:450px;margin-right:10px">
     <script src="ajx/ajax.js"></script>

<strong>This is the jobcard details (updates every 5 seconds):</strong>

<script type="text/javascript">
refreshdiv();
</script>
<div id="timediv"></div></div>

Comment: how to store multiple row value into mysql. see this jsfiddle file       http://jsfiddle.net/SeLUN/

Comment: get value from table row and set into text box. see my jsfiddle file [ http://jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/ ]

Comment: you have to put class of td and id of respective input same and copy all values see this http://jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/1/

Comment: thanks once again @Bhushan Kawadkar. Is this possible in jquery,see this [ jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/1 ] , when i click insert button , some status will updated in mysql. two operation in single button

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jquery(as you have tagged this question with jquery), you can use index() function form jquery (http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Here is an updated (http://jsfiddle.net/6yXMF/) jsfiddle. 
Which alerts index of the tr from which the input button is clicked.

Currently there are some issues in insertion and deletion or rows in your code. After resolving the issues you just can use the index function as demoed in 
`insRow()` function.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: when i click of '#',that particular row getting disappear and data moving to top row.

Comment: Check if this (http://jsfiddle.net/ctQpR/) works for you.
Note: Remove alert for row index if you don't need it any more